# Issues installing swiper.js (node.js/grunt noob)

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, bower, swiper.js

Having issues getting swiper.js to work. Requires grunt/bower. I'm completely new to js generators and am only able to get through about half the walkthrough before running into issues.

When I type $grunt dist into terminal, I get the following response: -bash: dist: command not found

What step am I missing?

Followed the idangerous steps to the letter: http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/plugins/scrollbar.php

Answer (score 0):

I have most often see "X command not found" for one of the following reasons:

1. The project's Grunt dependencies aren't installed or aren't installed properly
2. Your Gruntfile is mis-configured or missing

To fix this, first make sure there is a package.json file in your project.  This will tell the npm what dependencies the project has and install them accordingly (assuming the package.json file is also configured correctly).

Next, make sure you have [installed grunt](http://gruntjs.com/installing-grunt) correctly.

If you're still having issues, open your Gruntfile and search for:

```
grunt.registerTask('dist
```

This will show where the "dist" task is being defined.  If you for some reason don't find it, then there's your problem.  If you do find it, then check the proceeding commands inside square brackets that look like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('dist', ['clean', 'dist-css', 'copy:fonts', 'dist-js', 'dist-docs']);
```

'clean', 'dist-css', etc. are all other tasks defined in the Gruntfile, and there could be an issue with those as well.

If there's an issue with your package.json or Gruntfile, then trying re-installing the project with bower and repeat the above steps to ensure that it's not an issue on your end.

If it's not, then something is probably wrong with the author's source code.